# Counting certain kinds of Semistandard Young Tableaux

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, young-tableaux

We have a project in which it is natural to count the number of Young Tableau in which part of the weight has been specified.  Does anybody know if this idea already appears in the literature?

More specifically, fix a shape $\lambda$.   Given $i = (i_1,\ldots,i_k)$ we set $K_{\lambda}(i)$ to be the number of all semi standard Young Tableaux of shape $\lambda$ with entries in ${1,\ldots,m+k}$ and whose first part of the weight is equal to $i$.  So these $K_{\lambda}(i)$ are a kind of “contracted Kostka number” (our terminology)

Do these $K_{\lambda}(i)$ already have a name, or do they already appear somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren't these just skew tableaux ?

Comment: I don’t think these are skew tableaux. But anyways there is an obvious way to express the number as a sum of Kostka numbers.

Comment: Another way to express the number is as the coefficient of $x^i$ in $s_{\lambda}(x_1,\ldots,x_k,1,\ldots,1)$ (Schur polynomial where we specialize the last $m$ variables to 1.)

Comment: This does not ring a bell, but you can see that these are in bijection with lattice points in some type of hybrid Gelfand-Tsetlin polytope: https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/gtpatterns.htm You basically specify certain row sum constraints now on only some of the rows.